# How do "Indeed.com" and "hotelscombined.com" search other sites?

Tags: search-engine

I'm trying to build a vertical (meta) search engine for a particular industry. I'm trying to do somthing similar to "indeed.com" (job search engine) and "hotelscombined.com" (hotel search engine). I would like to know how do these two search engines build up their search results?

1) Is it using APIs of the other websites they serve results from? (seems odd to me since some results come from small and primitive sites).

2) Do other website post updates to these search engines? (Also seems odd as above)

3) Do they internally understand and create a map for each website they serve results from? (if so, then maybe they need to constantly monitor the structure of these sites for any changes. Seems error prone to me).

4) Any other possibilities?

I don't know even where to start, so any pointers in the right direction is much appreciated. (books, tutorials, hints, ideas...)

Thanks

Comment: I'd start by hiring someone who's run an aggregation/search team elsewhere. And yes, at any of these companies, it's a well-funded, well-staffed _team_ doing aggregation work.

Comment: That said, for playing around on your own, you might look at the Apache Project's scraper for a place to start: http://nutch.apache.org/

Comment: well budget is an issue (as usual) so hiring is no option, but thank you for the Nutch hint.

Answer (score 0):

It is mostly a mix of 1 and 3. Ideally, the site will have some sort of API they expose and document. If not, you have to do [data scraping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_scraping). Basically, you reverse-engineer their page. If they get results asynchronously via an undocumented API, you can use that API as well as (until they make a breaking change). Otherwise, it's simply a matter of pulling the text straight out of the HTML.

I don't know of any more advanced techniques since I don't do this myself, but several of my acquaintances have gone on to work on mobile apps that need to do this sort of thing with sports scores and such (not for searching, but same requirements - get someone else's data into our database). The low tech "pull it from the HTML until they change the HTML and break everything" is standard practice where they work.

2 is possible, but to do it you have to either make business arrangements with every source of data you want to use, or gain enough market presence for everyone to want to upload their data.

Also, you don't do this while actually searching (unless you have other constraints as Charles Duffy points out in his comment). You run a process that regularly goes out, gets all the data it can find, and inserts it into your own database, which you then search. This allows you to decouple data gathering from data searching - your search page won't have to know about and handle errors from the scraper, and the scraper has to only "get all the data" from each source instead of being able to transform queries from your site to search each source.

Comment: Thanks. Very much appreciated. I am starting by purchasing a book on IR "Information Retrieval" from Amazon. You are right, data scraping is the way to go until you get enough market presence.

Comment: Well -- I know of at least one aggregator that actually _does_ run queries in real-time with no local retention for legal purposes. All depends on what you're doing / who you're scraping...